# For em JavaScript com valor digitado pelo usuário

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um campo de um formulário que recebe um valor `inteiro`, esse campo no formulário possui a função `OnKeyPress`, preciso que ao usuário digitar algum valor esse valor vá para o `for` ex: o usuário digitou `5`, o `for` vai de `0 a 4`

Minha função em `JavaScript`:

```
function key_press(e) {
  for (var i = 0; i < e; i++) {
    $("#gridContainer2").dxDataGrid("addRow");
  }
}
```

Meu formulário:

```
@(Html.DevExtreme().Form<FormaPagamentoViewModel>()
    .ID("formularioCadastro")
    .ShowValidationSummary(false)
    .Items(items =>
    {
       items.AddGroup()
       .Items(groupItems =>
       {
         groupItems.AddSimpleFor(m => m.Fpg_quantidade)
         .Editor(e => e.NumberBox().Width("70px").OnKeyPress("key_press"));//Campo que o usuário ira preencher
    });
    })
    .FormData(Model)
    )
```

Comment: E qual é o erro?

Comment: Na vdd o erro é que o meu for eu n to passando o valor digitado, estou passando apenas o "e", mas eu testando descobri uma solução

Comment: Eu devia ter comentado a parte que precisa de alteração, desculpe erro meu, mas obg

Comment: Não tem como em vez de onKeyPress, colocar `.OnKeyUp("key_press(this)")`?

Comment: Sim, tem como, até se parece melhor de utilizar

Comment: Mas não entendo bem a diferença entre os dois

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em vez de `OnKeyPress`, use `OnKeyUp`, porque o primeiro irá retornar o valor que estava antes de você pressionar o teclado, enquanto que o segundo irá pegar o valor após, o último valor digitado. Coloque um `id` no campo e pegue seu valor usando `document.getElementById`:

```
.OnKeyUp("key_press")
```

Na função você faz:

```
function key_press() {
   for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementById("ID DO ELEMENTO").value; i++) {
      $("#gridContainer2").dxDataGrid("addRow");
   }
}
```

Note que não precisa do `(e)` na função, já que nada está sendo enviado para ela.

Comment: Não consigo enviar elementos via `this´, o campo do formulário some

Comment: Possui o atributo de Width, porém como é do devextreme, pode ser que crie algum id automaticamente

Comment: Sim, consigo colocar um id, mas não sei como pegar no javascript usando esse id

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementById("ID DO ELEMENTO").value; i++) {`

Comment: Tentei dessa maneira, mas o debugger fala que q o valor é undefined

Comment: Troque `ID DO ELEMENTO` pelo `id` que vc colocou no campo.

Answer (score 0):

Testando, acabei encontrando a seguinte solução:

```
var event = e.event, str = event.key || String.fromCharCode(event.which);
for (var i = 0; i < str; i++) {
    $("#gridContainer2").dxDataGrid("addRow");
}
```

`Event.Key` pega o valor digitado e coloca em `var str` que pode ser usada no `for`.